# preventing multiple ajaxcalls not working

Tags: jquery

i wanted to prevent multiple ajaxcalls but with my code nothing happens anymore?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var isProcessing = false;

function updatePartij(){
    if(isProcessing) return;
    isProcessing = true;
    $.ajax( { url: 'heartbeat.php?uwBeurt=' + uwBeurt + '&w=' + w + '&ka=' + ka,
                succes: {isProcessing = false;}
                error:  {isProcessing = false;}
                    });
    setTimeout('updatePartij()', 4500);  
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

typo and missing comma

```
succes: {isProcessing = false;}
error:  {isProcessing = false;}
```

and they should be  functions

```
success: function(){isProcessing = false;}, //<--- comma
error: function(){isProcessing = false;}
```

I don't like writing lines twice but why not do this?

```
function updatePartij(){
    $.ajax( { url: 'heartbeat.php?uwBeurt=' + uwBeurt + '&w=' + w + '&ka=' + ka,
        success: function(){
           setTimeout('updatePartij()', 4500);  
        },
        error: function(){
           setTimeout('updatePartij()', 4500);  
        }

};
```

Comment: That's also still invalid syntax.

Comment: it works now! thank you, but got another problem: it keeps on going to do the ajaxcall? the timeout seems not to work? (maybe my real problem?)

Comment: Dont know what i did now, but it works perfectly:) thank you, it kept me busy for 2 hours:)

Answer (score 2):

```
succes: {isProcessing = false;}
```

This is invalid syntax.

You need to pass a *function*:

```
success: function() { isProcessing = false; }
```

Also, `success` has two `s`s.